# Persistent link of the present version of a file on Wikimedia commons

Tags: wikimedia-commons

Is is possible to get a persistent link of the present version of a file on Wikimedia commons?

Say I want a persistent link to the media displayed on https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Syrian,_Iraqi,_and_Lebanese_insurgencies.png

I believe I can get a persistent link to the previous version of the media with the link: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/archive/1/11/20160629140629%21Syrian%2C_Iraqi%2C_and_Lebanese_insurgencies.png where we have the "archive" directory.

However, a link to the present version seems only to exist with https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/11/Syrian%2C_Iraqi%2C_and_Lebanese_insurgencies.png - without the "archive" directory. As far as I understand this link will be overwritten when a new version is made and the file will be moved to some yet unknown location. Is that correct?

I do not see any explanation on this in the [Wikimedia Commons description about overwriting existing files](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Overwriting_existing_files#Linking_files).

Comment: A Wikimedia Phabricator task related to this question is available at https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T139294

Comment: [Extension:FlaggedRevs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FlaggedRevs) must contain code to retain the old image under conditions when it is overwritten at Wikimedia Commons: When a file at Wikimedia Commons is overwritten, the old version is shown in Wikis having FlaggedRevs enabled until reviewed locally. This is also why some Wikis implemented reviewer bots that review mass changes made by bots at Commons. de.wikipedia.org is one.
Not exactly a persistent link, only the file contents shown are kind of persists. Still an option for private Wiki installations concerned about copyright